# Zsh: Smart autocompletion feature?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I have the following alias in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
~ which pulseaudio-restart 
pulseaudio-restart: aliased to killall pulseaudio && pulseaudio --start
```

Is it possible to configure Zsh in a way that typing `restart` will output me `pulseaudio-restart` as a suggestion since it contains the string `restart`?

Currently, typing `restart` only brings up:

```
~ rest
restart        restore-trash
```

Comment: Why don't you name the alias `restart-pulseaudio`? Since you are using tab completion, it doesn't appear that the exact name of the alias matters that much.

Comment: Good point. However, for me it is easier to remember `pulseaudio-restart` because I know that I am looking for a command related to `pulseaudio`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For this you have to set/modify the `matcher-list` style for the completion module. This can be done with the following command:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'l:|=* r:|=*'
```

This tells the completion to look for completion on the left as well as on the right side of the typed word (specifics can be found in `zshcompwid(1)`).

As the name `matcher-list` indicates, there may be more than one match specification, in which case it is important that `'l:|=* r:|=*'` is the first one. The specifications are tried in the order they appear until something returns a match.

---

For `oh-my-zsh` the `matcher-list` is set in `lib/completion.zsh` and it already contains the required specification, but only as the last option. You can either change the order there or add your own settings in `~/.zshrc` after `oh-my-zsh` is loaded.

Comment: Very nice solution! Although I do use `oh-my-zsh`, I just added `zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'l:|=* r:|=*'` to the bottom of my `~/.zshrc` and it works perfectly!